# Javascript functions and objects using equal operator

Tags: javascript, function, object, equals, operator-keyword

I am trying to understand Javascript concepts from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript .
Please see the code below;

```
function personFullName() {
  return this.first + ' ' + this.last;
}

function personFullNameReversed() {
  return this.last + ', ' + this.first; 
}

function Person(first, last) {
  this.first = first;
  this.last = last;
  this.fullName = personFullName;
  this.fullNameReversed = personFullNameReversed;
}
```

I am confused why function personFullName() is called like

```
this.fullName = personFullName;
```

why it is not called like;

```
this.fullName = personFullName();
```

And same for the below;

```
this.fullNameReversed = personFullNameReversed;
```

I know functions are objects in javascript but i am unable to understand this concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `Person` object is assigning itself a **method**, not the results of a function. That is the reason it **doesn't call the function**.

This way you can do this.

```
var p = new Person("Matt", "M");
p.fullName(); // Returns "Matt M"
p.fullNameReversed(); // Returns "M, Matt"
```